# Apollo Client - refetchQueries after multiple updates

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo client 3 and trying to build an editable table

I have multiple API mutations and I should trigger the refetchQueries after the last mutation.

For example:

```
  const [updateName] = useMutation(updateNameD)
  const [updateAge] = useMutation(updateAgeD)
  const [updateCity] = useMutation(updateCityD, {refetchQueries: () => [{ query: UsersDocument }],})
```

The issue: the order of the mutations won't be always the same and I need to refetchQueries inside the last mutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another workaround:
The useQuery hook return also a refetch method,
then you can use it wherever you want

```
const [updateName] = useMutation(updateNameD)
const [updateAge] = useMutation(updateAgeD)
const [updateCity] = useMutation(updateCityD)
const {data, refetch} = useQuery(UsersDocument)

await Promise.all([updateName(), updateAge(), updatedCity()])
refetch()
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the three mutation needs to be executed at a time, then you can combine the the three mutation query into one query and your refetchQueries will get executed only after the mutation query(combined one) will finish. Please not when you combine the query you will have only one `useMutation` hook.

Let me know if you have a different use case.

[EDIT]
If you cannot group query, below can be the approach.

```js
const [updateName] = useMutation(updateNameD)
const [updateAge] = useMutation(updateAgeD)
const [updateCity] = useMutation(updateCityD)
const [refetchPageData] = useLazyQuery(UsersDocument)

Promise.all(updateName(), updateAge(), updatedCity()).then(res => {
    refetchPageData()
})
```

Comment: Yes it's a different use case, I can't combine the queries. I need them separate and I don't have a way of knowing the order they will be called